# About abstract class design

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I currently have this structure, where `Collider` is an abstract class.

[image: Collider class structure]

I want to create another abstract class `LevelObj` which should have a `Collider`. Any inherited classes of `LevelObj`, such as `Wall`, then has to further define which one of the colliders it needs. Then I wanted to create the object `Level` which has a container of `LevelObj`. This way I would have access to all functions of both `Collider` and `LevelObj` from `Level`.

This method however is not possible, since `LevelObj` cannot hold an abstract class. And even if it could, I would not be able to 'change' the object `Collider` in any of his children for the inherited classes of `LevelObj`.

Is there any way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Have a `std::unique_ptr<Collider>` member.

Comment: Have a look at the *decorator pattern*, it might help with your design. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create an instance of an abstract class.
... but you can have a pointer or *pointer-like* type to the abstract class, that at run time time gets to point to instances of the derived classes (that can be instantiated because they're not abstract)

So you have a choice of

- pointers: You must deal with the ownership, i.e. who must have the task of creating/destroying that instance.
- references: I don't feel comfortable with references as attributes. A reference is more or less like a pointer, but it uses different syntax... and cannot be null... So your control of the lifecylce of the referenced object must be tighter.
- higher level (dealing on its way with the lifecycle of the referenced objects), unique_ptr, shared_ptr...

All of them can point to an instance of any of the derived classes... and accessing it as an abstract class

Answer (score 1):

> This method however is not possible, since LevelObj cannot hold an abstract class.

That is certainly true. However, it can hold a pointer or a reference to an object of an abstract class. The actual object can be embedded in the derived class, like this:

```
class LevelObj {
public:
    Collider &collider;
protected:
    LevelObj(Collider &c) : collider(c) {}
};
class Wall : public LevelObj {
private:
    ColliderRect wallCollider;
public:
    Wall() : LevelObj(wallCollider) {}
};
class Fence : public LevelObj {
private:
    ColliderMesh fenceCollider;
public:
    Fence() : LevelObj(fenceCollider) {}
};
```

The above assumes that subclasses of `LevelObj` are "married" to their colliders. If that is not true, use `unique_ptr<Collider>` in the base, and initialize it from the constructor of the derived class by supplying a pointer to an allocated collider to the base class.

> Then I wanted to create the object `Level` which has a container of `LevelObj`

Since `LevelObj` is polymorphic, you should use a container of smart pointers to `LevelObj` - `unique_ptr<LevelObj>` if level objects are not shared among levels (or within the same level) or `shared_ptr<LevelObj>` if level objects are shared in any way.